# Mistaken prism assembly reference in visual studio

Tags: prism

I am using prism and I get an exception that: The type 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Bootstrapper' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

the problem is that I already have an assembly reference to Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition in my project

any help? thanks

Comment: Hi, I have same problem. If you found any solution please let me know :)

Comment: Hi, I really don't remember finding a solution. What I found out is that I don't really need Prism. So I dropped the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.UnityExtensions` need a reference to `Microsoft.Practices.Prism.Composition` assembly. 
Just download [Prism 5.0 for WPF](http://aka.ms/prism-wpf-code), compile the source code of `ModularityWithUnity.Desktop.sln` at `\Source\Quickstarts\Modularity\Desktop\ModularityWithUnity` and copy all Prism assemblies from `bin\Debug` directory and paste it in your app's location.

This fixed my same problem.